# The auditorium of the theater on the heat map

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I need to display the most popular seats in the auditorium on the heat map. I have a list of rows and seats and the number of tickets purchased for a period of 1 year. The task is trivial if not for one thing. The auditorium has the shape of a trapezoid. The number of seats in the last rows is less than in the first, so the usual heat map is not visual. I would be grateful if someone could suggest an idea how to turn a rectangular map into a trapezoidal one.

Data can be found here: [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aMc_DNS63qWIuyWGthSJW4m8N9erUp1p/view?usp=sharing)

Output:
[image: heatmap output]
A solution that didn't satisfy me:

```
fig = px.imshow(df)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assignment is an assignment in the realm of `pandas`, not `plotly`. I'm sure there are other smarter ways, but I would find the number of columns excluding NA for each row, subtract the number of columns obtained from the maximum number of columns, and divide that by 2 to get a symmetrical form. Combine that into a new data frame. Finally, I transpose which data frame to use.

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for i,cols in enumerate(df.count(axis=1).tolist()):
    all_cols = len(df.columns)
    offset = int((all_cols - cols) / 2)
    df_new = pd.concat([df_new, df.iloc[i].shift(offset)], axis=1)

import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

fig = px.imshow(df_new.T)

fig.update_layout(template=None, autosize=False, width=800)
fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=np.arange(1,31))
fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=np.arange(1,20))

fig.show()
```

[image]